# SQLite 3 Tree List Without CTE

Tags: sqlite, common-table-expression

I adapted a SQL statement to work with SQLite 3. But unfortunately Common Table Expressions and WITH clause works only in SQLite 3.6 ahead, but the users of my Open Source application are using SQLite 3.2 and I cannot force them to update the whole Linux system to get the new packages. Is it possible to adapt the code to work without using a CTE and  "With" Clause using only SQL Language?

Here's the code:

```
WITH 
cte AS 
   (SELECT 0 AS level, collectionID, collectionName, parentCollectionID, CAST(collectionID AS VARCHAR(128)) AS Sort
           FROM collections WHERE parentCollectionID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT p.level + 1, c.collectionID, c.collectionName, c.parentCollectionID, CAST(p.Sort || '/' || CAST(c.collectionID AS VARCHAR) AS VARCHAR(128))
          FROM collections c
          INNER JOIN cte p ON p.collectionID = c.parentCollectionID)
SELECT 
collectionID, 
printf('%*s', level * 4, '') || collectionName AS collectionName, 
Sort,
parentCollectionID 
FROM cte
ORDER BY Sort;
```

Here's the result:

```
collectionID    collectionName            Sort     parentCollectionID
1               Dissertação               1        0
10              Filosofia Reformacional   10       0
11              Dooyeweerd                11       0
14              ZotPad favorites          14       0
15              Diversos                  15       0 
2               Bíblia                    2        0
3               Políticas Públicas        3        0
4               Zotero                    4        0
5               Linux                     5        0   
6               Tese Doutorado            6        0
12                  Pontal Do Paraná      6/12     6
7                   Multimodal            6/7      6
13                     Modalidades        6/7/13   7
8                      Base Histórica     6/7/8    7
9              Artigo Weber               9        0
```

Thank you so much,
Best regards,
Christian

Comment: You could try it with a recursive inline function. No clue if that is supported by SQLite though.

Comment: Hi Florian Schmidinger, I never used inline functions. Please, how can I do it?

Comment: Please Florian Schmidinger , how can I send to you the data?

Comment: Ok Florian Schmidinger, I edited the question with the information you need ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69962/discussion-between-florian-schmidinger-and-britto).

Comment: Cross post: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/90710/1822

Comment: @Britto sorry, i cannot solve this... i just found out that sqlite supports views but no user defined functions of any kind... my guess is that you have to manage this with code (java,etc.). i should have looked up supported functionality before i started this

Comment: Thank you so much @Florian Schmidinger! I'm glad that you tried to help me. Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

CTEs were added to SQLite because they cannot be emulated with any other SQL language constructs.

The recommended way of using the SQLite library is not to link to some random version that comes with the OS, but to add a copy of the `sqlite3.c` file directly to your application.
This prevents both version and configuration conflicts.

Comment: Thank you so much CL. I'll check if that's possible with the programming language I use ;)